# How can I check if a GameObject contain a meshrenderer but not contain any collider and then add a collider to it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddColliders : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToAddCollider = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AddDescendantsWithTag(transform, objectsToAddCollider);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void AddDescendantsWithTag(Transform parent, List<GameObject> list)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() != null
                && child.gameObject.GetComponent<)
            {
                list.Add(child.gameObject);
            }
            AddDescendantsWithTag(child, list);
        }
    }
}
```

At this line I'm checking that there is a mesh renderer attached to the gameobject but how do I check if it don't have attached any collider type ? And then how to add a mesh collider to it ?

This is what I tried so far :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddColliders : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToAddCollider = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        AddDescendantsWithTag(transform, objectsToAddCollider);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void AddDescendantsWithTag(Transform parent, List<GameObject> list)
    {
        foreach (Transform child in parent)
        {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() != null
                && child.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>() == null)
            {
                child.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
                list.Add(child.gameObject);
            }
            AddDescendantsWithTag(child, list);
        }
    }
}
```

But then in the end when adding a break point on the line :

```
AddDescendantsWithTag(transform, objectsToAddCollider);
```

I see that the gameobjects in the List objectsToAddCollider in the Collider this message :

collider = System.NotSupportedException: collider property has been deprecated

[image: Collider]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GameObject.collider`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-collider.html) was deprecated and removed in version 2019.1.0.

You can't use it for debugging anymore.

---

To check if there is a `Collider` of any type use

```
var collider = child.GetComponent<Collider>();
```

to simply check if it exists you could also do

```
if(child.GetComponent<Collider>())
{
    Debug.Log("Collider found");
}
```

again since `Collider` (or better said Unity's type `Object` from which it inherits) implements an [implicit `bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) which equals `!= null`.

---

A very nice way to add the component if it does not exist in a single line is therefore

```
Collider collider = child.GetComponent<Collider>() ? collider : child.gameObject.AddComponent<Collider>();
```

or even slightly shorter

```
Collider collider = child.GetComponent<Collider>() ?? child.gameObject.AddComponent<Collider>();
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*

Comment: But if I'm doing if(child.GetComponent<Collider>()) I'm checking if there is a collider but if there is no collider it will not get inside. I want to check objects that have mesh renderer but dont have any colliders and then to add to it a collider. Isn't if(child.GetComponent<Collider>()) meaning like if(child.GetComponent<Collider>() == true)

Comment: I'm getting error on the line : var collider = child.GetComponent<Collider>() ? collider : child.gameObject.AddComponent<Collider>(); on the collider after the ? Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0841 Cannot use local variable 'collider' before it is declared

Comment: That's why I said *again*... The second `if` block is just for you debugging if it succeeded. I'ld recommend to use the one liner instead to do both the check and the adding in a single line.

Comment: Yeah sorry .. for the one liner you have to explicitly define the type .. you can't use `var` there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Collider as it is the base class for all colliders.

```
    private void AddDescendantsWithTag(Transform parent, List<GameObject> list)
{
    foreach (Transform child in parent)
    {
        if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() != null
            && child.gameObject.GetComponent<Collider>()) // You can modify this line according to your requirement. 
        {
            list.Add(child.gameObject);
        }
        AddDescendantsWithTag(child, list);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html

According to unity documentation it is still present in 2019.x

Comment: @akaBase nope! Read the API carefully: Using `gameObject.collider` was removed and using `GetComponent<Collider>()` is **the way to go**.

Comment: @derHugo my bad, not use to having a header saying its outdated and then showing a different supported method without making any reference to the change of method other than the code itself.